# Set cookie for request in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to load a page using CapserJS, but how can I send cookie which was exported from chrome's http request header at that page?

Such as:

> "SUB=_2AkMjHt3gf8NhqwJRmPkQzG_qZIp_yA3EiebDAHzsJxJTHmMJ7IUyLkMN2K7WzRJvm-Tv3YY0xyZo; SUBP=0033WrSXqPxfM72-Ws9jqgMF55529P9D9WhCT_2hbJ1W1Cc4xfF-mFPo;"

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways, but the easiest would be to use the [`page.addCookie`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/add-cookie.html) or [`phantom.addCookie`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/add-cookie.html) functions which PhantomJS provides, but you would have to set the domain (and path). Keep in mind that `page.addCookie` has to be done on a loaded page whereas `phantom.addCookie` can be done before.

```
var cookie = "someCookieName=Value; otherName=Value";
var domain = "example.com";
cookie.split(";").forEach(function(pair){
    pair = pair.split("=");
    phantom.addCookie({
      'name': pair[0],
      'value': pair[1],
      'domain': domain
    });
});

casper.start("http://example.com", function(){
    // check that cookie was indeed set:
    this.capture("screen.png");
}).run();
```

Comment: @user2518430 I have no idea why some people have a problem with this, but I can say that the `domain` property is very important. [Here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/eead7b3da73d138be12de5681aa95b80) is an example script where it works for me. Create a screenshot with the `addCookie` call and one without to see whether there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the cookie headers directly like this:

```
casper.start().thenOpen('http://yoururl', {
    headers:{ "Cookie" : "CookieName=cookieValue" }
  }, function() {
    // ...
});
```