# How to pass the cookies get from document.cookie to phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

phantomjs has a parameter `--cookies-file` and I can point it to a cookie file. Its format is like:

```
[General]
cookies="@Variant(\0\0\0\x7f\0\0\0\x16QList<QNetworkCookie>\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0lBAIDUPSID=9C185C46016DC114CB8ECCDE512C768B; expires=Tue, 10-Nov-2082 20:14:15 GMT; domain=.baidu.com; path=/\0\0\0oBAIDUID=9C185C46016DC114CB8ECCDE512C768B:FG=1; expires=Sat, 15-Oct-2044 17:00:09 GMT; domain=.baidu.com; path=/)"
```

Here I want to know, if I have the cookies string got from `document.cookie` on a website, how to pass it to phantomjs `--cookies-file`? I'm not sure how to convert the format.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26448950/1816580 if you don't want to convert it to this file format which is probably a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Artjom! You've helped me a lot.